# How to apply a parameter to packet so TC can prioritize\classify it

Tags: networking, socket, tc

I want to add a parameter to the packet so that I can later let TC (HTB in specific) prioritize my packet (based on filtering that parameter).
I thought about filtering by `socket` but as I understand it isn't part of the packet , is there anything else I can alter in order for TC to filter these packets ?

I know about `net_cls` but it distinguishes only `cgroups` while I want to distinguish flows with the same task id.

Answer (score 0):

found `SO_MARK` which sets a mark for each packet sent through a specific socket.